# Freely available library for creating os x configuration profiles

Tags: macos, configuration, mdm

On OS X you can create configuratio profiles (which are ordinary XML Files). In them, you can configure for exampe VPN tunnels, Wi-Fi Connections or other stuff, like screen saver timeout or so. Normally you create them using "Profilemanager" on OS X Server.

Those keys are documented by apple, here: [Apple Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneConfigurationProfileRef/Introduction/Introduction.html)

I am looking for a library which can create an XML for me with those keys.
For example I could call it and it would create a new configuration profile for me, with a VPN tunnel in it with properties I supplied when calling the library.

Are you aware of such a piece of software, or do I have to write it by myself?

Regards
Me

Comment: Since you're obviously not doing this on the iOS device side, what language are you using? Also have you tried on your own first? There are many XML creation plug-ins for almost every modern programming language that would make this easy.

Comment: Hey
Well, I am not to fixated on a specific language. So everythink I know would be easy: python, java, C# or PHP.

As there does not seem to exist something I will write something by myself, most probably in java. 
The problem isn't the creation of the xml file but the combination of all the keys and payloads, which I would have liked to left out if there was allready something, but this doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: I guess I'm not completely following. Your config profiles don't need *all* the keys. For instance if you're only configuring WiFi you wouldn't need to include the empty keys for a VPN config.

Comment: Oh well of course, I only need to create the keys I want to configure!
But I would like to support as many as possible of them, to configure the clients of my company as flexible as possible (Apples profilemanager is nothing you'd like to use in your environment..)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar Problem: I wanted to enable my users to create profiles themselves (but with values I deposed for them in advance).

I ended up storing those 2 or 3 keys I needed in a php page which the users can Access and this php-code creates the XML and offers it for download.
No Need for a Special library.
Of course, if you are going to Need all ekys, or create lots of profiles, you are free to start a new Project, for example on github, and let everyone Profit from it!